# Bad results in keras after Warning: tf.function retracing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I just started to use keras and tesorflow to create a simple multilayer perceptron with 3 inputs, one hidden layer with 10 neurons and one neuron as the output. I trained the network and the results were okay with a 'val_mean_absolute_percentage_error' of about 5 %. I played around with some parameters of the training (especially the epochs) and trained the model several times. All of a sudden, when predicting one value I get the following warning that I do not understand

> WARNING:tensorflow:6 out of the last 11 calls to <function
> Model.make_predict_function..predict_function at
> 0x0000023C7D1EAAF8> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is
> expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1)
> creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with
> different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For
> (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2),
> @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes
> argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please
> refer to
> https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#python_or_tens
> or_args and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for more details.

The very strange thing is that after this warning occured I get very bad results having a 'val_mean_absolute_percentage_error' of about 125% and also the prediction results are quite bad.

As I am also new to python, I do not understand the possible reasons in the warning message. Why did this warning and the bad results all of a sudden occur and how can I get rid of them? I'd appreciate every comment and would be quite thanful for your help.

Here you see the model that I created

```
#Create the model

#Input shape defiens the number of input neurons
input_shape = (3,)

#Sequential model is just one for a vanilla MLP
model = Sequential()
# This line creates the hidden layer with 10 Neurons. The input layer is also specified with 3 Neurons
model.add(Dense(10, input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

# Print summary
model.summary()

# Configure the model and start training

model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mean_absolute_percentage_error'])
model.fit(X_input_dataset, Y_output_dataset, epochs=10, batch_size=10, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)

#predict values
x_new = [(1,1,1)]
print(x_new)
y_new = model.predict(x_new)
print(y_new)
```

Update: Here you can see my data. I have 3 numbers (inputs) and one number (output) which is just the sum of the 3 input numbers

```
1. Number   2. Number   3. Number   Result
10  13  5   28
2   19  4   25
1   4   16  21
13  5   8   26
9   5   12  26
10  13  0   23
0   4   14  18
1   16  12  29
7   0   3   10
17  14  3   34
1   1   12  14
15  2   8   25
7   18  4   29
8   14  12  34
4   1   11  16
8   16  12  36
13  17  13  43
17  7   4   28
16  10  14  40
16  4   13  33
5   2   10  17
3   13  20  36
9   4   14  27
20  13  20  53
3   14  9   26
12  1   19  32
2   16  9   27
```

Comment: Did you change the input(data) or something else?

Comment: Thanks Frightera for your comment. No, basically I did not change anything. This is why I am quite suprised about this behaviour. The only thing I did was retrain the model several times varying the number of epochs.

Comment: @Frightera: Any comments on my last comment? I'd highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: What is your data? I tried to reproduce the issue with random uniform data but I could not get your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Frightera. I updated my question adding the data and the aim of the ANN (Unfortunately I do not know how to add a table in stackoverflow; this is why the formatting does not look that good)

Comment: Did you try to scale your data?

Comment: No I did not scale anything. I just used them as they are. As mentioned before, the very strange thing (to me) is that at the beginning everything worked quite well and then (for me) all of a sudden this problem occurs and the results are quite bad. So I would like to understand what the problem exactly tells me and why it did not occur at the beginning but after some time (after having done several loops with higher number of epochs)?

Comment: So basically the main purpose of my question was not to make this toy example work (I can do this by setting a huge number of 1000 epochs) but to understand this problem in general as I suppose that it can occur in many other applications

Comment: I also could not understand how this happened in this case to be honest.

Comment: Thanks Frightera for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. When does this warning usually occur and is it common - based on your experience - that the results of training an ANN differ so extremeley significantly after such a warning (from 5 % error to 125 % error after 10 epochs)?

Comment: This *retracing* happens when input has changed, like shape or dtype etc. You can [try this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38561#issuecomment-613894395). Your ANN might diverge here, I don't know if this has something to do with the warning directly.

Comment: Thanks Frigthera for your comment. What do you mean by saying "Your ANN might diverge here"? Another thing that I noticed is that (I use Jupyter notebooks) that when re-running the cell that contains the training code, the validation error gets lower all the time as if a re-run of the cell is just an increase of the epochs. Is this a usual behaviour?

Comment: When you re-train, you are training on the previous learnt weights. So it can keep learning. Diverge means maybe you overshoot the minimum so your model won't be able to learn.

Comment: Thanks Frightera for your answer. No I did not overshoot the minimum. Anyways, thanks for your effort. So the problem seems not be solvable. I will try different ANN configurations and different activation functions hoping that the problem does not occur again